# Login & registration redirects - don't redirect login when on checkout page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, checkout

My code works as expected but it should not redirect the user when they login while on the checkout page.

I used `is_checkout()` to try and detect this but it is not working as expected.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'bbloomer_customer_login_redirect', 9999, 2 );

function bbloomer_customer_login_redirect( $redirect ) {

    if ( is_checkout() ) {
        return '/checkout';
    } else {
        $redirect = '/my-account'; // custom URL same site
        return $redirect;
    }
}

// define the woocommerce_registration_redirect callback 
function filter_woocommerce_registration_redirect( $redirect ) { 
        $redirect = '/my-account'; // custom URL same site

        return $redirect;
 }

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'filter_woocommerce_registration_redirect', 9999, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

This should suffice

```php
function filter_woocommerce_login_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
    // Checkout 
    if ( $redirect == wc_get_checkout_url() ) {
        $redirect = '/checkout';
    } else {
        // Get the "My account" url
        $redirect = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) );
    }
    
    return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'filter_woocommerce_login_redirect', 10, 2 );

function filter_woocommerce_registration_redirect( $redirect ) {
    // Get the "My account" url
    $redirect = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) );
    
    return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'filter_woocommerce_registration_redirect', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: This does not work. Redirects to white page that is same URL that the user was already on. The issue with my code  if ( is_checkout() ) - for some reason it cannot detect that it is on the checkout page already.

Comment: `$redirect == wc_get_checkout_url()` will be true if you are on the checkout page, 
so you could use this instead of `is_checkout()`. What do you mean with _"don't redirect"_ ? 
after logging in you still stay on the same (checkout) page, 
is this not the intention? as already applied in your original code